# Expiring Session in CodeIgniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have many ajax function in my code.When I simultaneously click the link the session expires,
I don't know why this happens?? I tried lot of updations in the sessions.php and config.php but still it the problem exist.

please help me with this......

Comment: No code to share ?

Comment: Do u want me to share my ajax code??? i 've called ajax in every 2 and  5 minutes .

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the answer...

its just, we need to add

```
$config['cookie_domain'] = ".example.com"; //your site domain
$config['cookie_prefix'] = "example_";
```

in config.php